# MDX query not evaluating 'Greater Than' expression

Tags: sql-server, mdx, data-warehouse

I have an MDX query that has a weird evaluation behavior.

here is the query

```
Select {[Measures].[Alert Count]} ON 0, 
 Hierarchize([Alert].[Alert Type].Levels(1).Members) ON 1 
 From(SELECT { Filter(Hierarchize([Alert].[Alert Type].Members), 
([Measures].[Alert Count] < 2000))} on COLUMNS From [Data DW])
```

On the expression `[Measures].[Alert Count] < 2000`, it evaluates correctly giving me the `[Alert Type]s` with `[Alert Count] < 2000`, same thing for equality comparison but when I change the condition to 'greater than' , it gives me all the values including those less than or equal.

After some tests, I found that the condition 'greater than' evaluates correctly only if the compared value (2000 in the example) equals to the total number of records in the measure table. I deduced that in this case, it's not grouping the results by `[Alert Type]`.

any help about this problem, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The issue was in the `filter` syntax, specifically in the first `member`. I had to add the `hierarchy level` to the filter set, so it became:

```
[Alert].[Alert Type].Levels(1).Members
```